# PostgreSQL - Could not extend file No space left on device. HINT: Check free disk space

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, storage, postgresql

I've been inserting data into PostgreSQL DB, and got the error message:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not extend file "base/16384/61892": No space left on device
HINT: Check free disk space
```

I am using CentOS 7, and I've checked some of my status on my linux machine:

`df -h`

[image]

I'm pretty new to Linux, and based on the result of my `df -h` command, I could see that Linux storage system works differently than Windows.

It looks like PostgreSQL is pushing to `/dev/mapper/centos-root`, but it has only 50 GB available.

**Question 1:** How can I change it? How can I assign the extra free space that's available in `/dev/mapper/centos-home` to my `~/centos-root` directory?

**Question 2:** My machine has two Hard disk, 200 GB each. But according to my `df-h` command, it looked like I only have 200GB available. Why is this the case? How can I take advantage of full 400GB space?

It looks like the problem is that my `/dev/mapper/centos-root` is all filled up. I have inserted nearly 10,000,000 rows of data with 12 columns in PostgreSQL.

**Question 3:** Is this big enough to take up 50GB of space?

Thanks!

Edit: output of `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs`

[image]

Comment: Please post the output of `pvs; vgs; lvs`

Comment: @shodanshok please check the update. Also, what are the significance of each commands?

Comment: @EricKim  (almost) every command comes with an online manual that will give you between a hint and an encyclopaedia's worth of information on what the command does and supported switches etc.; try [`man pvs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pvs) , [`man lvs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvs) and the manual for the manual system [`man man`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/man)  - but the relevant output of the command sequence shows how much of your physical disk(s) , physical volume and logical volume space is assigned and available

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your server is badly partitioned. This is not entirely your fault; rather, the default RHEL/CentOS settings are quite misleading in my opinion.

Let's start from the description on the `pvs; vgs; lvs` command entered above. They are all related to [`LVM2`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvm), a Logical Volume Manager which, in short, enable you to create "flexible", resizeable partitions:

- `pvs` shows how the physical disks are attached to the LVM system. You had 2x 200 GB disks, but `pvs` only shows 1x200 GB physical device. This means your disks are in RAID1 (mirroring) and they are wholly assigned to LVM (ie: no physical space is unassigned);
- `vgs` shows the Volume Group assigned to your physical devices and any usable free space. In your case free space is <4 MB, so basically you have no space free space. The next command explains what is using your space...
- `lvs` shows you have two Logical Volumes (think them as partitions): a 50 GB root volume and a ~145 GB home volume. In short, your `root` volume (where PostgreSQL resides) is way smaller than your needs; rather, your `home` volume is very large considering how few data (< 5GB) it contains.

To solve the problem, you have two options:

- relocate PostgreSQL under the `home` volume, for example under `/home/pgsl`. I would avoid this because `/home` is not the right place for a database and it *will* cause an administrative burden in the future. Moreover, you need to put SELinux into permissive mode (`setenforce 0` + `/etc/selinux/config` editing) to let the relocation work;
- shrink the `home` volume and enlarge `root`. This is easier said than done, especially if you are using XFS (default RHEL/CentOS filesystem), which does not support shrinking.

**If and only if** your data under `home` can be trashed / reloaded, you can follow the following steps to **DELETE** the `home` volume and enlarging `root`. Please note that a small error (both mine and your) **WILL** destroy your data (killing any cats in a ~100 KM range), and so I take ***NO RESPONSABILITY*** for the final outcome. If you are unsure, **stop here and call a professional sysadmin** for support. Ok, let's go ahead; I'll post a command sequence with the relative description:

- `umount /home`: this unmount (ie "disable") the home volume;
- `lvremove centos/home`: this *permanently destroy* `/home` and *all* its content;
- `lvextend centos/root -L +100G`: this expand the `root` volume by 100 GB;
- `xfs_growfs /`: assuming you are using XFS, this expand the root filesystem to match the underlying, extended volume. If you are using `ext4` (which is improbable), you need to issue `resize2fs /dev/centos/root`.

Comment: It would be at least prudent to first have a look at what /home contains before nuking it, and recreate /home and remount it afterwards else problems will probably occur later...

Comment: run "ls -l /home" and "du -sh /home/*" before destruction (and regrets.

Comment: then "lvcreate -L10G centos home", "mkfs.xfs /dev/centos/home", mount "/home"

Comment: You'll probably need to recreate the user home directory you're using to log into the system (because YOU MUST NOT LOGIN AS ROOT). "cp -r /etc/skel /home/user && chown -R user:users /home/user"